# When does albert launcher update its index?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, search, albert

I am enjoying using the Albert Launcher on Wasta Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 with Cinnamon desktop manager). It usually works well, but sometimes doesn't find files I am looking for.

In my experience, search programs can look immediately for what I want, which takes time, but shows information about the system as it was when the search happened.
Others maintain an index and search that, which is much quicker. But they show results based on the system as it was when the index was last updated.

Albert seems to have an index (because it's so fast :-) but I can't find any way to ask it to update the index now, nor to ask it to update the index at 2 AM every day.

I have read the sections of the help and tried to chat via Telegram with @albertlauncher (as suggested there) without success.

Can someone point me to an answer to my question, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a rescan manually in the settings or via "albert scan files". Files rescan interval can be set in the settings. The files extension has an index in memory. For the entire disk use the locate wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @manuelschneid3r
"albert scan files" worked.
I looked in the settings, but couldn't find anything about rescan interval.
Thanks for this great program.

Comment: Check the extensions tab and click files.